# Como acessar uma página HTML e retornar o seu HTML usando Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin-forms

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para acessar uma página, exemplo uol.com.br, e retornar o seu HTML. Para junto como esse retorno tentar utilizar as expressões regulares com esse HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private async void GetHtml()
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://xamarin.com");
    }
}
```

> Fonte:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237829/how-to-read-html-from-a-webpage-using-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

Simples.

Usando a classe [**`WebClient`**](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.WebClient/#memberlist) de [`System.Net`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://uol.com.br");
}
```

Ou usando [**`HttpClient`**](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.Http.HttpClient/) de [`System.Net.Http`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var html = httpClient.GetString("http://uol.com.br");
}
```